# Class members created on stack or heap?

Tags: c++, class, heap-memory, stack-memory

Need to know if such a 3d matrix would be created in the stack or on the heap and if its on the stack how to new it and initialize default values correctly (memset)

```
class Matrix {
     protected:
         int n[9000][420]; // is stack or heap if VVV is pointer?
};

void main()
{
         Matrix* t = new Matrix(); // created on heap
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that depend entirely on whether you use `new` or not? What is your real question?

Comment: Well is it implied on the heap since `t` is on the heap, and it's a member of the class.  I know a similar but local scope variable would just be stacked.

Comment: `n` is a part of `Matrix` like your liver is part of you.  If you're on the "heap", then your liver is also on the "heap".

Comment: @user1139252: `t` is not "on the heap". `t` is a local, automatic variable in the function scope of `main`.

Comment: @user1139252: flagged as offensive.  Also, Kerrek's point is that `t` is a pointer variable with automatic storage duration ("on the stack"), where as the `Matrix` instance created by your `new` statement has dynamic storage duration ("on the heap").

Comment: @user1139252: Ok, well he's right and you are wrong.  The variable `t` is a pointer which is allocated with automatic storage duration, i.e., on the "stack".  What it points to is dynamically allocated on the heap.

Comment: @user1139252: Not sure what you mean by that.  Are you referring to the disease *asperger's* syndrome, or hamburgers that come from the rear end of some creature?  Either way I stand confused... are you saying that such a distinction is irrelevant?  I find it hard to believe that someone with even a small modicum of experience would hold that opinion.

Comment: @user1139252 : If you want a real answer then pedantry is necessary; would you prefer we gave vague/incorrect answers in an effort to avoid details, even if pertinent? I think not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all comes down to how you create the parent object.

```
MyClass {
    int n[10];
};

int main(...) {
    MyClass *c1 = new MyClass; // everything allocated on heap, 
                               // but c1 itself is automatic
    MyClass c2;                // everything allocated on stack
    // ...
}
```

Heaps and stacks are of course an implementation detail, but in this case I think it's fair to specify.

Comment: Without context, it looks like your `c1` and `c2` are have *static* rather than automatic storage, though!

Answer (score 0):

The array `n` is a direct member of the class `Matrix`, so any object instance of this type contains the data for `n` directly. In particular, if you create a dynamic object in dynamically allocated memory, then the array will be there; and if you create an automatic object, the array will be reside the automatic memory as well.